# Center ul but keep left-aligned

Tags: css

I created a simple page with Bootstrap and would like my ul to be center aligned on mobile but with the text left aligned. I tried setting text-align to left and the right and left margins to auto in my CSS file, but it isn't centered:

[image: mobile view]

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/JLwGdY)

Here's the CSS applied to the ul:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  /* Bottom set to 3em to match margin above ul created by blockquote */
  margin: 0 auto 3em auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`display:flex;`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: just like @YaakovAinspan said, you can use flex to achieve this. 
display: flex; justify-content:center; to center your container, then align your text using text-align:left;

Comment: Display: flex causes the list items to appear horizontally rather than vertically. (I would like to keep them displayed vertically.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If you are looking for this solution, you need to add padding-left:0

```
ul {
  /* text-align: center, applied to parent jumbotron class, only works on inline elements; applying this ensures ul is centered */
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  /* Bottom set to 4em to match margin above ul created by blockquote */
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
```